# Blocking answer field in a list

Tags: list

I'm creating a list that will auto populate certain fields via a SPD workflow.  Is there any way to grey out those fields or make it to where the person filling out the fields is unable to?  I'm using SharePoint 2013 Standard and do not have InfoPath.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a couple ways to do this:

1. Using Powershell, go into the list, get the fields you do not want users to fill out, and set their `ShowInNewForm` property to `false`.
2. Add Javascript to the New form for the list that either disables the controls for those fields, or hides them entirely.

Comment: Thanks!  I'll give these a shot!  Do you know if I hide them entirely, when I open up to view the list it will show the fields?

Comment: If you are using Javascript to hide them on the form, you are really only manipulating the HTML of the form page when it loads in the browser, so that would not affect the structure of the list or the views.  Google for "sharepoint hide form fields javascript" and you will find tons of examples.